# SQL Query to Retrieve Multiple Varients based on ranges of inputs and existing data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset that I am trying to query to get discount rates. The challenge is that the dataset holds discounts for only a subset of the possible query inputs.

In some cases, I can get an exact discount rate from the data. In others, I need to get the nearest matches (higher and lower) and then externally compute the discount from the returned data.

Consider a dummy dataset as follows:

[image]

If I have an exact match, then it is easy to figure out the discount. For example, with Freq of 5, Duration or 2 Order Quantity of 50, the discount is 0.10402.

However, if the Frequency was 7, and the Duration was 6 and order was 50, I would need to be able to have returned the next lowest and next highest matching rows and then compute the actually discount independently. eg: would want to have the follow retrieved:

Next Lowest (eg: Freq 5) = 0.10402
Next Highest (eg: Freq 10) = 0.31048

Finally, if I don't have an exact match for either Frequency nor Duration, I need 4 results to compute the discount independently! Eg:

Discount rate for:

(Low/Low) Nearest Freq that is LESS than & Nearest Duration that is Less than

(Low/High) Nearest Freq that is LESS than & Nearest Duration that is Greater than

(High/Low) Nearest Freq that is GREATER than & Nearest Duration that is Lower than

(High/High) Nearest Freq that is GREATER than & Nearest Duration that is Greater than

So I think I need a query that will return between one and 4 rows depending on the inputs supplied and how well they match the data. Specifically:

One row if there is an exact match on Freq and Duration.

Two rows if (say) Freq matched exactly. First row would be rates for next lowest Duration, second for next highest duration.

Four rows if nothing matched exactly, eg:

1st Row) Nearest Lower Freq & Nearest Lower Duration

2nd Row) Nearest Lower Freq & Nearest Higher Duration

3rd Row) Nearest Higher Freq & Nearest Lower Duration

4th Row) Nearest Higher Freq & Nearest Higher Duration

Hopefully this makes some sense! Anyone got any suggestions on how to write a query that would achieve same? Have tried lots of different ways, but getting quite tangled up in it!

Thanks!

Here is a sample query that I can run today to get back an exact match!

```
select Rate from RateTable
 where ProductId=34343
 and ProductVariationCode='G497'
 and ProductStatus=0
 and Frequency=23
 and Duration=4
 and 100 >= MinOrder
 and 100 < MinOrder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method might be `union`:

```
select . . .   -- your logic combining the values
from ((select top (1) t.*
       from t
       where frequency <= @frequency and duration <= @duration and
             @order between minorder and maxorder
       order by frequency desc, duration desc
      ) union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      (select top (1) t.*
       from t
       where frequency >= @frequency and duration <= @duration and
             @order between minorder and maxorder
       order by frequency asc, duration desc
      ) union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      (select top (1) t.*
       from t
       where frequency <= @frequency and duration >= @duration and
             @order between minorder and maxorder
       order by frequency desc, duration asc
      ) union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      (select top (1) t.*
       from t
       where frequency >= @frequency and duration >= @duration and
             @order between minorder and maxorder
       order by frequency asc, duration asc
      )
     ) t;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am afraid I am struggling to figure out how to integrate what you have provided with the 'basic' queries that I have already crafted! The following query (as an example) will return a single result if everything matches: select Rate from RateTable
  where Frequency=23
  and Duration=4
  and 100 >= MinOrder
  and 100 < MinOrder

Comment: Not sure how to modify what I have to integrate what you have provided!!

Comment: @Jablalr . . . The comparisons on the order need to go in the subqueries.

Comment: have edited my original question to provide a sample of the SQL that I use now. Obviously, this only works and returns a result in the case where there is an exact match on Frequency and Duration. Could you please show me how to integrate what you provided? Please!

Comment: WAIT!....figured it out and understand now. Thats exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a million!